# Where is gradle build tools version set?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have installed sdk build tools version 28.0.2, and set buildToolsVersion = "28.0.2" in build.gradle. Yet when I run `./gradlew installDebug`, I get an error message saying `The SDK Build Tools revision (23.0.1) is too low for project`.

I even UNinstalled version 23.01.1 via the android studio sdk manager - but then when I run gradlew it reinstalled it!

I ran `grep -ri buildtool *` to try and find where it might be, but the only reference I could find was in build.grade.

I managed to work around this by upgrading my gradle version to 3.1.0. But as a result, I now get this message:
`WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (23.0.1) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (27.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.1.0.`

Which tells me that the SDK Build Tools version **is** being set... somewhere!

Where else is the required build tools version set? How do I change it so that gradle will use the latest version, rather than being stuck on an old one?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The buildtoolsversion is defined in build.gradle(Module.app).

I removed this line from the file and then the warning disappeared.